# Exception Handling Not working in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

we have a below procedure to update/insert a table. I have added exception handling in stored procedure as below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_UPDATESP
@Workstationlist worktable READONLY
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @rerror As int
SET @rerror = 0

BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN
                MERGE [dbo].WORKTABLE AS [ofc] 
                USING @Workstationlist AS [Source] ON [ofc].officeid = [Source].id
                WHEN MATCHED THEN 
                UPDATE 
                    SET NumWorkStations = [Source].wsno, 
                        ModifiedBy      = [Source].modifiedby, 
                        ModifiedByUsername = [Source].modifieduser, 
                        ModifiedDate = GETDATE() 
                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                INSERT ( officeid, NumWorkStations, ModifiedBy, ModifiedByUsername, ModifiedDate )
                VALUES ([Source].ID,[Source].wsno, [Source].modifiedby, [Source].modifieduser,GETDATE() );

                SET @rerror = @rerror + @@error 

                If @rerror = 0 
                BEGIN
                    COMMIT TRAN
                END

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
           SELECT @rerror AS ErrNum
ROLLBACK TRAN
End Catch

SET NOCOUNT off
END

GO
```

When I execute the procedure with an exception (passing null to id column)  as below

```
declare @Workstationlist worktable
insert into @Workstationlist VALUES ( NULL,500,106720,106720)
EXEC     USP_UPDATESP @Workstationlist
```

I got @error as 0 Always . Is there any problem this way of error handling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to me it looks like you are mixing `TRY...CATCH` error handling with old style error handling.

the code:

```
SET @rerror = @rerror + @@error
```

cannot be reached because when an exception occurs the control is passed to the catch block so the `@rerror` variable will always be 0, the value initially set.

in the catch block you should leverage the proper structures/objects to access error information and drop all the old way completely.

something like this:

```
    BEGIN CATCH;
        DECLARE @ErrSev     INT,
                @ErrMsg     NVARCHAR(MAX),
                @ErrState   INT;

        SELECT  @ErrSev = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
                @ErrState = ERROR_STATE(),
                @ErrMsg = isnull(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), '(unknown procedure)') + ': ' + isnull(ERROR_MESSAGE(), '(unknown message)');

        RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSev, @ErrState);

    END CATCH;
```

Answer (score 0):

Catch the error in proper way.

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    SELECT 'Success' AS Result
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    SELECT 'Failed' AS Result
        ,ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
END CATCH;
END
```